# Should a comma be used whenever it resolves an equivocation?

Tags: commas, ambiguity

I think I may nearly have got commas, but am not sure.

Should a comma be used whenever it resolves an equivocation?

What about the following:

- She got angry with him, ignoring his stupidity

The possible equivocation seems obvious. And I can't think of it meeting any [definition](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427531/when-do-absolute-phrases-lack-a-noun) of a parenthetical phrase. But I'm not sure if the end phrase is ungrammatical so needs a rewrite instead.

Comment: Yes, the comma helps clarify. However, to be perfectly clear I might have said "Ignoring his stupidity, she got angry with him".

Comment: thanks @WS2 and my version is grammatically ok?

Comment: Yours is ok, but even by adding the comma it still does not 100% free the sentence of ambiguity. Ie. Who was doing the ignoring, him or her?

Comment: oh ok that as the entire point of the comma! @WS2

Comment: Uh… Pardon? @WS2… How could that possibly mean the one doing the ignoring was him? Either way if the comma clearly does reolve an ambiguity   that would otherwise remain yes, it should be used.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin *She got angry with him, (because he was) ignoring his stupidity - an unlikely, but idiomatic elision*. Better would be *She got angry with his ignoring his stupidity*.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely correct and the comma is needed. The -ing form of the verb is a "gerund" in this sentence. They are tricky. The entire phrase functions as a noun, in this case, providing additional information about the subject 'She'. Within the phrase, it functions as a verb and may take object and adverbs.
As to your question, 'Should a comma be used whenever it resolves an equivocation?', the answer is, "Yes! ... Always!"

Comment: _Ignoring his stupidity_ was a clever move. That's a gerund. _Ignoring his stupidity,_ she got angry with him. That's a participle.